# Copy an OS drive with all its partitions, to a bigger hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, ddrescue

I have a Windows machine, and it's OS is alongside with the a few more partitions on one hard drive.

I want to use Ubuntu live cd, in Order to copy that OS drive to another, bigger hard drive and utilize that space.

I managed to copy the drive using ddrescue and it works fine, but then I have a lot of un utilized space on the new bigger drive.

I would like to os partition To use all the extra space

I tried to copy the partitions using Gparted and resize the OS partition, the system did not boot afterwords

I tried to use ddrescue to copy the drive, and then Gparted to change the partition's size, But it's not the last partition on the disk, so I could not, When I tried to resize the other later partitions and then "make room" for that partition and then resizing it, the machine did not boot afterwords.

How can I copy the drive, and keep it bootable, allowing one partition use all the extra space I have on the larger disk?

Thanks

Comment: After you copy the Windows partition to bigger drive, use Windows to expand the partition. Windows is more finicky about it's system partition than Ubuntu. Windows won't boot if you use Ubuntu or anything else to modify Windows partition.

Comment: Exactly as commented above. But you can use GParted to move the other partitions to the end of the new drive, creating unallocated space contiguous to the end of Windows system partition. Then boot Windows and use its native tool - Disk Management - to expand the system partition.

Comment: If this machine has only Windows and not Ubuntu as well, then I would use the Windows native tool to move and resize the partitions. Unlike Ubuntu, Windows allows you to move and resize the partition it is booted from.